# Should I put all the constructor parameters in the interface to be resolved for the Unity?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, prism, unity-container

I am using Prism with Unity to do the IoC. I have some classes that have some value type parameters (e.g., string path, int number) in their constructors.

How should I deal with these parameters if I want to resolve these classes?

Should I put these parameter into interface or should I put them into a function and call it after the class is resolved?

Thanks,

Wei

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register types that implement those interfaces. When you do you can specify the constructor parameters for instantiating the class, and you can provide the actual values or ask the container to inject a resolved reference. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882(v=pandp.20).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923(v=pandp.20).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried a lot of different approaches (e.g. registring simple values with specific names, I tried to configure such things in entry point, when you configure your whole DI container, etc.), but they all aren't clear at all and increase complexity of your code. IMHO, single (few) interface like `IConfiguration` is the most clear, robust and maintainable solution.

So, now I use this way in almost all my applications:

```
interface IConfiguration
{
  string ConnectionString { get; }
  int MaxLevels { get; }
}

class Configuration: IConfiguration
{
  string ConnectionString { get { return "BlahBlah"; } }
  int MaxLevels { get { return 123; } }
}

myUnityContainer.RegisterType<IConfiguration, Configuration>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager();

class YourClass
{
  public YourClass(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    // Use settings from "configuration"
  }
}
```

Of course, usually all these properties actually return values from App.config file (or from database)

PS. Remember, that your code should be not only "clean and theoretically good", but the main feature of good code is maintainability and robustness. Anyone should open your code and immediately understand what you meant here. IMHO, this solution matches this criteria more than others.